# AzureDevops Deployment Group won't run on Windows Server 2019

Tags: azure-devops, devops

Hi I have a new on prem server DELLEMC and I'm trying to run the deployment group registration script but the script won't run and after a while this error will appear  "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "

I also refer to this link for help but it didn't work https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/263

[image]

Comment: Here is the exact error

Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The operation has timed out."
At line:1 char:1303
+ ... nalString, $True);}; $WebClient.DownloadFile($Uri, $agentZip);Add-Typ ...
+                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> AzureDevops Deployment Group won't run on Windows Server 2019

According to the error message:

```
Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The operation has timed out."
```

It seems there is something wrong to download the agent, please try it again. Note, make sure the network is fast and stable. If this issue still exists, please do the following steps:

1. Download [the agent bits](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/releases) from here and select the v2.162.0 or
   above . User can download it from other machine and copy that to
   this machine if the download is failing because of network issue.
2. Extract the zip in some folder.
3. Open PowerShell admin command prompt and go to the folder
4. Run the below PowerShell script as an administrator:

   ```
   .\config.cmd --deploymentgroup --deploymentgroupname "{deploymentGroupName}" --agent $env:COMPUTERNAME --runasservice --work '_work' --url 'https://iam-costco.visualstudio.com/' --projectname '{ProjectName}'
   ```

You could check [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1012383/unable-to-download-resources-for-deployment-group.html) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for helping, yes we have a slow internet connection in our place but I will try your instructions you gave me.